# The meaning of attitude in a sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm discovering the word ***prevalent*** and faced [this example](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prevalent):

> This negative attitude is surprisingly prevalent among young boys.

I couldn't find a suitable meaning [in the dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/attitude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, the word ***attitude*** means how the boys' feelings manifest in their behaviors. Presumably, in this case, they manifest negatively.

The word ***prevalent*** means common, widespread, approaching ubiquitous. Other synonyms: omnipresent, ever-present, everywhere, all over the place, pervasive, universal.

So one could rewrite the sentence as follows:

> Making surly and sarcastic comments while moping around the house is common behavior for young boys.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is taken out of context: the word *this* should refer to something in the previous sentence, which we don't have.  So we cannot say for certain what it means.

However, most likely, the sense of *attitude* used here is the first one in the definition you quote: "someone’s opinions or feelings about something".  An attitude could be said to be *negative* if it consists of unfavorable opinions or feelings about something.

A plausible context for this sentence could be something like:

> I asked my grandson Jim how he felt about cookies, and he said "I hate them."  This negative attitude is surprisingly prevalent among young boys.

In this example, Jim says he hates cookies; we could say that he has a *negative attitude* toward cookies.  The second sentence expresses that many other young boys feel the same way - this *negative attitude* is *prevalent* among them.  The word *surprisingly* suggests that the attitude is *more* prevalent than the reader probably expected.  Perhaps you would have guessed that only 1% of boys hate cookies, but the actual number was 30%.